# AuthorizeRouteView Not working for logged out users

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

We are starting to migrate a project to blazor, and are having some issues with restricting content to only logged in users.

For this test, we have used a standard Visual Studio 2019 Blazor Server-Side project template, with local users and accounts authentication enabled.

We have then changed the App.razor file to the following:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
<Found Context="routeData">
    <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
        <NotAuthorized>
            NOT AUTHORIZED!!!!!
        </NotAuthorized>
        <Authorizing>
            AUTHORIZING!!!!!
        </Authorizing>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
</Found>
<NotFound>
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </CascadingAuthenticationState>
</NotFound>
```

The code in `<NotAuthorized>` never gets hit, I have confirmed no cookies on the browser, and even tried in a private browser window as well.

I have in a different component injected the HTTPContext to see what is going on with the current user. Current user is not null, it has an identity, but is showing an unauthenticated, and has no claims as expected.

Is there something i am missing here?

Answer (score 8):

For AuthorizeRouteView to work, it needs to be clear which pages/components require authorization. You can use an authorize attribute:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@page "/counter"
@attribute [Authorize]
```

Comment: Beautiful, after I added `@attribute [Authorize]` to my root page (the one that says `@page "/"`), AuthorizeRouteView's __NotAuthorized__ suddenly started working. Is there a way to convince it to treat all pages as requiring authorization, without adding @attribute [Authorize] to all of them?

Comment: @Arsinclair Add the ``@attribute`` in the ``_Imports.razor`` file at the top level or corresponding folder level, instead of adding it to each file.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem with the current Blazor version in a WebAssembly (client) project.

It would be nice if the Blazor team could tell us what we do wrong, because you use exactly the code they suggest to use.

I found a workaround by using an `<AuthorizeView>` in my MainLayout. There the `<NotAuthorized>` part is executed correctly and you can use the code they suggested [to force a redirect to log on](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13709#issuecomment-528665136):

```html
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <!-- Markup of your MainLayout -->
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <RedirectToLogin />
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put `Router` inside `CascadingAuthenticationState`:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    NOT AUTHORIZED!!!!!
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    AUTHORIZING!!!!!
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```